# movies in beamer - compatible (free) pdf-viewers

Tags: beamer, pdf, viewers, multimedia, video

Via the multimedia package in beamer, I have included a movie in my slides.

This works fine if the pdf is openened in Adobe Pro DC, but unfortunately not with the free version of Acrobat Reader (there is a tool 'multimedia', but when clicking on it, I get redirected to the Adobe website for an upgrade to pro).

Are there other pdf-viewers that work fine for such movies, especially free ones?

I'm interested especially in something that works on Windows 10

Comment: Which operating system do you use (from mentioning Adobe Pro DC I am guessing it is either Windows or Mac, but not Linux)?

Comment: @Marijn added it

Answer (score 0):

While not really being able to recognize the movie that was included using LaTeX, Foxit reader allows one to add a video after the pdf has been compiled, this seems to be a useful workaround.

Answer (score -1):

back then we created a Latex FFF parser for Factorio's FFF.

In that time, we wanted to embedded videos in the pdf. We did it via [media9 package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/media9).

You can see part of what instantiating the figure looks like here:
https://github.com/LaTrissTitude/FactorioFridayFactsLaTeX/blob/master/FFFLaTeX/configSymbols.py#L80

Answer (score -2):

Look at 10.1 example in this book https://github.com/AnMnv/eBook

I used it not in beamer, but may be it will help you somehow